# Creating one hot encodings from a column of dictionaries with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project that uses a public IMDB Dataset and looking to extract the genre data from each sub-string and store this information in separate columns. This is what I currently have.

Current:
ID Genres
1995 [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]

What I'm trying to achieve
is to separate the data into each genre, that corresponds to the Movie ID eg, Movie ID
1995: Action, Adventure, Fantasy, Science Fiction

So all in all I have multiple strings that contain what I want, I would like to extract the relevant data (genres) for each ID.

How can I do this in python, i've been playing around with pandas but can only currently get a True/false for one type of genre.

CSV File [here](https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Order of the Column headers for the re-arranged data

Genres = ['Action','Adventure','Biography','Comedy','Crime','Documentary','Drama','Family','Fantasy',
          'Film-Noir''History','Horror','Musical','Mystery','News','Romance','Sci-Fi','Short','Sport',
          'Thriller','War','Western']

os.chdir('C:\\Users\parmi\Documents\Python Scripts')
org_data = pd.read_csv('tmdb_5000_movies.csv')


film_id = pd.DataFrame(org_data)['id']
genre_data = pd.DataFrame(org_data)['genres']

genre_data= genre_data.str.extract(Genre)
genre_combined = pd.concat([film_id,genre_data], axis=1)
genre_combined.to_csv('genre_data2.csv')
```

Comment: start with posting the code you have including demodata in panda

Comment: Do you want columns of 0s or 1s depending on whether the genre is included?

Comment: Yes, that would work perfectly for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: See answer below and please mark it accepted if it was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load in your data -

```
df = pd.read_csv('tmdb_5000_movies.csv')
```

Next, `genres` contains JSON data, so load it as a column of dicts -

```
v = df.genres.apply(json.loads)
```

Next, flatten your data using `np.repeat` -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'id' : df['id'].values.repeat(v.str.len(), axis=0),
    'genre' : np.concatenate(v.tolist())
})
```

Convert `genre` from a column of dicts to a column of strings by retrieving the `name` attribute from each dict.

```
df['genre'] = df['genre'].map(lambda x: x.get('name'))
```

Finally, compute one hot encodings using `str.get_dummies` -

```
ohe = df.set_index('id')\
        .genre.str.get_dummies()\
        .sum(level=0)\
```

```
ohe.head(10)

        Action  Adventure  Animation  Comedy  Crime  Documentary  Drama  \
id                                                                        
19995        1          1          0       0      0            0      0   
285          1          1          0       0      0            0      0   
206647       1          1          0       0      1            0      0   
49026        1          0          0       0      1            0      1   
49529        1          1          0       0      0            0      0   
559          1          1          0       0      0            0      0   
38757        0          0          1       0      0            0      0   
99861        1          1          0       0      0            0      0   
767          0          1          0       0      0            0      0   
209112       1          1          0       0      0            0      0   

        Family  Fantasy  Foreign  History  Horror  Music  Mystery  Romance  \
id                                                                           
19995        0        1        0        0       0      0        0        0   
285          0        1        0        0       0      0        0        0   
206647       0        0        0        0       0      0        0        0   
49026        0        0        0        0       0      0        0        0   
49529        0        0        0        0       0      0        0        0   
559          0        1        0        0       0      0        0        0   
38757        1        0        0        0       0      0        0        0   
99861        0        0        0        0       0      0        0        0   
767          1        1        0        0       0      0        0        0   
209112       0        1        0        0       0      0        0        0   

        Science Fiction  TV Movie  Thriller  War  Western  
id                                                         
19995                 1         0         0    0        0  
285                   0         0         0    0        0  
206647                0         0         0    0        0  
49026                 0         0         1    0        0  
49529                 1         0         0    0        0  
559                   0         0         0    0        0  
38757                 0         0         0    0        0  
99861                 1         0         0    0        0  
767                   0         0         0    0        0  
209112                0         0         0    0        0
```